# I need good introductory texts/publications on brain networks and functional integration/segregation

Tags: cognitive-psychology, cognitive-neuroscience, cognitive-modeling

I am a soon to be graduating applied mathematician interviewing for a research position soon in a lab considered with neurological imaging and association of brain networks with things like aging, combined tasks, etc.

In my opinion, I believe I have a strong repertoire of applied mathematics and research experience in applied mathematics/computation relevant to the task at hand, and I can talk comfortably about the skills advertised (data analytics, programming, experimental design, etc.). My background is in graph theory, computational biology, and systems modeling. However, I want to be able to communicate about brain networks and integration/segregation of the brain while factors such as aging, task completion, injury, etc. change during the interview. Therefore, I would love to skim some introductory texts or read some landmark papers about this field so I can sell myself as competent for the job.

While the job itself does not require the research assistant to be equipped with such information, I think it would be best to up the ante in terms of how I present myself. Could anyone recommend such texts or literature?

If it helps, I have an undergraduate degrees in biology/biochemistry so I'm relatively familiar with the nomenclature surrounding neurophysiology, neurotransmitters, etc. and I have a working knowledge of an introductory neuroscience and psychology course so I am familiar with theories of memory, and the different parts of the human brain.

Answer (score 3):

A good introductory book is "Networks of the Brain" by Olaf Sporns. It will give you a general overview of the ideas and theories in the field. For more details consult the bibliography or read some of the journal articles by Dr. Sporns.

https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/networks-brain

http://www.indiana.edu/~cortex/index.html